# pgfplots, TikZ interoperability and axis equal

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Sec. 4.27 of the pgfplots manual explains how to match pgfplots and Ti*k*Z unit vectors and origins. It suggests:

> 2. Configure matching unit vectors by means of the `x` and `y` keys. The default configuration of Ti*k*Z is to use `x=1cm,y=1cm,z={(0,0)}`. Note that these settings are usually overridden by pgfplots in order to respect `width` and `height` (and `view` for three-dimensional axes).

So I know that, if you want to match the two coordinate systems, you have to set explicitly the three unit vectors. Now suppose that I want to use the `view` key instead. I noticed that, if I use the `axis equal` option too, the origin doesn't match any more with the 2D origin (I mean the origin of the default 2D Ti*k*Z coordinate system). Look at the following example:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} [
  anchor=origin,
  at={(0,0)},
  disabledatascaling,
  view={135}{35.26},
  axis equal, % <-- this is the problem
]
\addplot3+ [only marks] coordinates {(0,0,0)};
\addplot3 [draw=none] coordinates {(1,1,1) (-1,-1,-1)};
\draw [blue] (0,0,0) node [above] {This is the 3D origin};
\fill [red, x=1cm, y=1cm] (0,0) circle (2pt) node [below] {This is the 2D origin};

\pgftransformshift{\pgfpointxyz{0}{0}{0}}
\pgfnode{coordinate}{center}{}{a}{}
\draw [thick] (a) circle (2pt);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you remove the `axis equal` option, the two origins will match. I'd like to know what is the problem and if there is any workaround for this behaviour.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is solved by updating PGFPlots.

Answer (score 3):

I believe there are two issues here: the first is an explanation for the red dot as it appears in the MWE and the second is to ensure that `axis equal` maps the 3D origin to TikZ's 2D origin.

What sounds like just one issue turns out to be two separate ones: if you move the `\fill[red,...]` instruction *outside* of the axis (but inside of the `tikzpicture`), both origins overlap (as desired).

Regarding the first question (why are the points at different locations): 
It seems that the `x=1m, y=1cm` instruction inside of an axis confuses the code which ensures that pgfplots integrates into tikz while it has its own coordinate system. Keep in mind that `(0,0)` combined with `compat=1.11` means to use `(axis cs:0,0)` implicitly. But it also seems that `(axis cs:0,0)` is not the same as `(axis cs:0,0,0)` inside of a 3d axis. I will look into it (perhaps the scaling transformation for z is not applied).

Comment: If it can be helpful, I've added a further example in the pgf language in which I've set no local coordinate system and I've used 3D coordinates instead of a 2D ones.